# Get current cursor position from multiline textbox without selection of any data

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to get current  cursor position from multi-line textbox without selection of any data from the textbox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea Is this what you want?

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea

Answer (score 0):

This vanilla JS [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKHbq/2/) should get you started.

```
var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

function mouseMove(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - textArea.offsetLeft,
      y = e.pageY - textArea.offsetTop;

  textArea.value = x + ", " + y;
}

textArea.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
```